Puppeteer Cannot Find Chromium in DigitalOcean App Platform's Custom Path
I'm trying to run a Node.js/Express application that uses Puppeteer to generate PDFs on DigitalOcean App Platform. Despite installing Chromium through an .aptfile, I'm encountering issues with launching the browser.
Environment
Platform: DigitalOcean App Platform
Node.js version: 20.x
Puppeteer version: Latest
Deployment: Using .aptfile for dependencies
Code
Here's my Express endpoint that uses Puppeteer:


import type { Request, Response } from "express";
import type { InvoiceRequest } from "./types/invoiceRequest";
import * as pug from "pug";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Precompile the Pug template once at startup
const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile("./templates/invoice.pug");

// Optional timeout middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setTimeout(60000, () => {
    res.status(504).json({ error: "Request timed out." });
  });
  next();
});

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.post(
  "/invoice/generate-invoice",
  async (req: Request<{}, {}, InvoiceRequest>, res: Response) => {
    console.log("Received request:", req.body);
    try {
      const invoiceData = req.body;

      // Calculate totals
      const subtotal = invoiceData.products.reduce(
        (sum, product) => sum + product.price,
        0
      );
      const vat = subtotal * 0.25; // 25% VAT
      const total = subtotal + vat;

      // Format dates
      const invoiceDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
      const dueDate = new Date(Date.now() + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        .toISOString()
        .split("T")[0];

      // Generate HTML using Pug template
      const html = compiledFunction({

      });

      // Use Puppeteer to generate the PDF from HTML
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
          "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
          "--single-process",
          "--no-zygote",
        ],
        executablePath: "/layers/digitalocean_apt/apt/usr/bin/chromium-bsu",
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: "A4" });
      await browser.close();

      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=invoice.pdf");
      res.send(pdfBuffer);
      // store the pdf localy
      fs.writeFile("invoice.pdf", pdfBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error saving invoice:", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Invoice saved successfully");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error generating invoice:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to generate invoice" });
    }
  }
);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});



This is my Aptfile:


chromium
chromium-common
chromium-sandbox
ca-certificates
fonts-liberation
libappindicator3-1
libasound2
libatk-bridge2.0-0
# ... [other dependencies] ...



This is the Error i am getting in digital ocean:

Error generating invoice: Error: Browser was not found at the configured executablePath (/layers/digitalocean_apt/apt/usr/bin/chromium-bsu)
at ChromeLauncher.launch (/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:76:19)


I decided to use const chromium = require("chromium");
// Use Puppeteer to generate the PDF from HTML
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--single-process",
      "--no-zygote",
    ],
    executablePath: chromium.path,
  });

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromium
